# Is it possible to aggregate over differing where clauses?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Is it possible to calculate multiple aggregates based on differing where clauses?  For instance:

Let's say I have two tables, one for Invoice and one for InvoiceLineItems.  The invoice table has  a total field for the invoice total, and each of the invoice line item records in the InvoiceLineItems table contains a field that denotes whether the line item is discountable or not.  I want three sum totals, one where Discountable = 0 and one where Discountable = 1 and one where Discountable is irrelevant.  Such that my output would be:

```
InvoiceNumber  Total  DiscountableTotal  NonDiscountableTotal
-------------  -----  -----------------  --------------------
1              53.27  27.27              16.00
2              38.94   4.76              34.18
3...
```

The only way I've found so far is by using something like:

```
Select i.InvoiceNumber,
       i.Total,
       t0.Total As DiscountableTotal,
       t1.Total As NonDiscountableTotal
From   Invoices i
    Left Join (
        Select   InvoiceNumber,
                 Sum(Amount),
        From     InvoiceLineItems
        Where    Discountable = 0
        Group By InvoiceNumber
    ) As t0 On i.InvoiceNumber = t0.InvoiceNumber
    Left Join (
        Select   InvoiceNumber,
                 Sum(Amount)
        From     InvoiceLineItems
        Where    Discountable = 1
        Group By InvoiceNumber
    ) As t1 On i.InvoiceNumber = t1.InvoiceNumber
```

This seems somewhat cumbersome, it would be nice if I could do something like:

```
Select   InvoiceNumber,
         Sum(Amount) Where Discountable = 1 As Discountable
         Sum(Amount) Where Discountable = 0 As NonDiscountable
Group By InvoiceNumber
```

I realize that SQL is completely invalid, but it logically portrays what I'm trying to do...

TIA

P.S. I need this to run on a SQL Server 2000 instance, but I am also interested (for future reference) if/how I would achieve this on SQL Server 2005/2008.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use:

```
  SELECT i.invoicenumber,
         SUM(CASE WHEN i.discountable = 1 THEN i.amount ELSE 0 END) AS discountable,
         SUM(CASE WHEN i.discountable = 0 THEN i.amount ELSE 0 END) AS NonDiscountable
    FROM INVOICES i
GROUP BY i.invoicenumber
```

To get any other columns in the INVOICES table (IE: total), you'll have to do a self join:

```
SELECT x.invoicenumber,
       x.total,
       y.discountable,
       y.nondiscountable
  FROM INVOICES x
  JOIN (SELECT i.invoicenumber,
               SUM(CASE WHEN i.discountable = 1 THEN i.amount ELSE 0 END) AS discountable,
               SUM(CASE WHEN i.discountable = 0 THEN i.amount ELSE 0 END) AS NonDiscountable
          FROM INVOICES i
      GROUP BY i.invoicenumber) y ON y.invoicenumber = x.invoicenumber
```

Comment: I don't know why I never thought of that... seems obvious now it's in front of me. Thanks.

Comment: +1 for the first code segment.  Unintuitive, but it works really well.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure about the actual syntax, but something like this should work:

```
Select   InvoiceNumber,
         Sum(IF(Discountable=1;Amount;0)) As IsDiscountable
         Sum(IF(Discountable=0;Amount;0)) As NonDiscountable
From Invoice
Group By InvoiceNumber
```

Comment: Yes, I can see it myself... in SQL it's WHEN and of course the parameters aren't separated by semicolons... Go with OMG ponies answer...